# How to detect if came back from child activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

How can I detect if an activity came to focus after pressing the back button from a child activity, and how can I execute some code at that time?

Comment: put your logic in the onResume() of your parent activity. so once U came back from your child it will execute.

Comment: @PadmaKumar That's incorrect. `onResume()` is called any time the parent activity becomes foreground, whether it's the first time, or is coming back from a child, returns from a modal dialog, or is launched the 5th time from a navigation drawer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you're looking for may be the onResume method you can implements in your mother class ;). You must know that the onResume is also called the first time you launch any activity. Look at the lifecycle of an activity : http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png

Regards,

Comment: So what will happen if on onResume i have a function update? On Activity first start/configuration change, update will also be called even if it is not intended.

Comment: How does this answer help? `onResume()` is called both when the mother activity first launches, and when you return there by pressing the back button from a child activity. So how are you supposed to detect the difference?

Comment: @LarsH simple. have a local boolean variable `isFirst` that is initiated with value false. on `onResume()`, first check if the `isFirst` is false. That means it's the first time the `onResume()` is called. Continue with setting the `isFirst` with true. Subsequent `onResume()` call will have the `isFirst` true.

Comment: @ChenLiYong: I think you mean the variable to be `isNotFirst`. But what is its scope and lifetime? Is it static? Where/when is it initialized? How do you ensure that it's not initialized multiple times? What if the user comes to the same activity twice *without* hitting the back button (there are many potential ways to navigate an app)? As you can see, there are multiple ways for this method to produce false positives and negatives.

Answer (score 14):

One possibility would be to start your child activity with [`startActivityForResult()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent%2C%20int)) and implement [`onActivityResult()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int%2C%20int%2C%20android.content.Intent)) which will be called when you return from the child activity.

Answer (score 7):

js's answer is right, but here is some debugged code.

Declare the request code as a constant at the top of your activity:

```
public static final int OPEN_NEW_ACTIVITY = 12345;
```

Put this where you start the new activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, OPEN_NEW_ACTIVITY);
```

Do something when the activity is finished. Documentation suggests that you use `resultCode`, but depending on the situation, your result can either be `RESULT_OK` or `RESULT_CANCELED` when the button is pressed. So I would leave it out.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == OPEN_NEW_ACTIVITY) {
        // Execute your code on back here
        // ....
    }
}
```

For some reason, I had trouble when putting this in a Fragment. So you will have to put it in the Activity.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer... but one minor correction in needed your code. The requestCode value range is from 0 to 65535. So, OPEN_NEW_ACTIVITY = 123456 won't work. So, I updated your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can also override both the onBackPressed() method and the onOptionsItemSelected() method and put some logic there. For example I put this into my BaseActivity which all the other Activities extends from:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // your logic
    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        // your logic
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```