# Android, how to detect that the activity is back from another activity?

Tags: android

For Android, suppose 3 activities, a1 a2 a3, with their click hierarchy, a1->a2->a3.

My questions is in a2, how to detect it is from a3 by pressing the back key, instead of entering from a1?

Comment: You mean if you press the back key at a2 it will pass you to a3?

Comment: When calling a2 from a1, add an extra in the intent to indicate it is from a1. So this extra would not exist if a2 was reached on a back press from a3. I have not tried this but theoretically sounds plausible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect if came back from child activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982081/how-to-detect-if-came-back-from-child-activity)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`onCreate` wont get called in case of back press.

There are multiple ways you can infer if you have arrived at this activity by back key press.

1. Set a `boolean` in oncreate that says on `onCreate` is called.
2. Start C activity by calling `startActivityForResult` and when you return from C `onActivityResult` will get called.

Comment: I don't think is safe to assume that onCreate() is never called in the case of a backpress.  Based on the docs it looks like onCreate would be called in the case of a back press if the system had called onDestroy() on the previous activity while it's in stopped state due to low system resources.  Source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: I believe this accepted answer is incorrect (@Deemoe's comment is right).

Comment: I agree. My 2nd option would work. However, there can be some better way to achieve the end goal without differentiating between back press and  new  launch.

Answer (score 15):

You can use `onActivityResult` to check for return from another activity. Put this code within your a2 activity.

Declare the request code as a constant at the top of your activity:

```
public static final int OPEN_NEW_ACTIVITY = 123;
```

Put this where you start the new activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, OPEN_NEW_ACTIVITY);
```

Do something when the activity is finished. Documentation suggests that you use `resultCode`, but depending on the situation, your result can either be `RESULT_OK` or `RESULT_CANCELED` when the button is pressed. So I would leave it out.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == OPEN_NEW_ACTIVITY) {
        // Execute your code on back here
        // ....
    }
}
```

You should take care to run `onActivityResult` on the Activity itself, and not a Fragment.

You don't actually have to put any code in the a3 activity, but you can send data back if you like.

Comment: I used this to detect when coming back from settings activity.

Comment: Your request code 123456 is throwing this error: Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode. Try to use a smaller code like 1 etc.

Comment: @abbujan Thanks, I'll shorten it. I just wanted to make it clear that it could be any number.

Answer (score 7):

You can use following methods

`onCreate()` when activity is first created ( from a1 to a2). This method won't be called when you come back via pressing back button.

`onRestart()` activity was in background and comes to foreground (back press in a3)

Comment: I wonder why nobody but you at this and another posts about same question suggesting `onRestart()` . It seems to be a rarely noticed lifecycle stadium. But that´s the only method that is definitely called once and only after go back.

Comment: Neither of these methods is correct. `onCreate()` can be called when the user presses the back button to return to the activity from its child after the process was killed (for example, the user may have picked the child activity from the task list). `onRestart()` is called when you return to the activity from anywhere, not just by pressing the back button from a child activity.

Answer (score 4):

Put some key in intent when you start your activity.

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), A1Activity.class);
   intent.putExtra("I_CAME_FROM", "a1");
   startActivity(intent)
```

And read it in opened activity:

```
   String flag = intent.getStringExtra("I_CAME_FROM");
   if(flag.equlas("a1")){
   //you came from a1 activity
   }
```

This will allow you to understand where you came from.

Comment: This is a good way to do it without using app-level flags or startActivityForResult.  You can also override the onBackPressed() function in your activity (a3) to send an intent with an extra indicating intent.putExtra("I_CAME_FROM", "BackButton"); and send it to (a2).

Answer (score 3):

You can detect that the activity is back from another activity by calling :

```
onRestart()
```

And add what you need in this function